# remove frontend/www from links

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I have yii::boilerplate, which have structure

```
backend
common
consol
fronend
```

uploaded to host. lets suppose domain is mysyte.com
in root directory i create .htacces next to the folderс.

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ backend/www/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ frontend/www/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

and so my site work fine. but  some troubles with URLs.

```
mysite.com/site/about   - work fine
mysite.com/frontend/www/site/about also work
```

And all links in href attribute contain 'frontend/www' prefix. So how to remove that my site not contain any links with 'ffornend/www' prefix

Answer (score 0):

Boilerplate is supposed to have the backend and frontend seperately thats the professional template structure

now you have to configure it like this

`www.mysite.com` will be mapped to `.../frontend/www/` as root

and

`admin.mysite.com` will be mapped to `.../backend/www/` as root

Comment: where to do this configuration? in .htacces? for now all works fine, but i dont want to see in url 'frontend/www'

Comment: you have to make this in httpd.conf file in server for the site and for the backend you can do in the same place but have to buy a new subdomain I hope but not sure of this. DO you use both backend and frontend??

Comment: Yes, backend for website administyration, its nor important what urls are there. but frontend is main website . i have no access to httpd.conf

Comment: http://myprogrammingtut.blogspot.in/2013/04/step-by-step-setup-yiiboilerplate.html Have a look at this STEP 2. This is how we configure boilertemplate in yii